# Time complexity - Big O - Show numbers from interval which are not in a file

Tags: c++, performance, time-complexity, big-o

I want to know that is the time complexity of this code (big-O):

(it reads a text file as follows:
on the first line is a number n and on the second line is a list of ascending numbers - max. n numbers - and it shows all the numbers from 1 to n which are not in the text file)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int interval(int a, int b, int &ok) { 
    for(int i=1; i<(b-a); i++) {
      cout << a+i << " "; ok=1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n=0, ok=0, a=0, b=0; 
    ifstream fisier("numere.in");
    fisier >> n;
    while(fisier >> b) { b
        interval(a,b,ok); 
        a = b;
    } interval(b,n+1,ok);
    if(ok == 0) cout << "Nu exista";
    return 0;
}
```

I think it is n*logn but I am unsure. Thank you

Comment: Which line is running n.log(n) times?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the complexity might be O(n log n)? Why do you doubt your analysis?

Comment: Thank you! I understand now why it is not n*logn. I though it was nlogn because when the file is, for example 100 on the first line and 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 (100 times on the second line), then first repeats to n and "for" is repeated approx n times but I was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If numbers are a1,a2,a3... a(n) then,

first it goes a1 times then in next iteration a2-a1 times ,  in next iteration a3-a2 times .... a(n) - a(n-1) times . adding this up gives a(n) times which is `O(n).`